Imenu in speedbar
The documentation to Imenu states:

Imenu provides the information to guide Which Function mode (see Which Function Mode). The Speedbar can also use it

My questions is: How do I add imenu entries to the speedbar?

To add support for Markdown, eval:
(require 'speedbar)
(speedbar-add-supported-extension ".md")


Usually, you don't have to worry about this: 
Speedbar (smartly) handles this automatically.
For example, there's a Python file a.py on my ~/Desktop:
def f():
    pass
class C:
    def m1(self):
        pass
    def m2(self):
        pass
def g():
    pass

Simply launch Emacs by emacs -Q and type M-x speedbar.
You can see there is a + sign before the filename:

Click at the + sign and you'll see the declaration list as shown in the imenu:


This seems to work for python files. I want that for markdown files though. markdown-mode populates imenu entries with heading entries, but these entries are not available in speedbar, neither on the files display nor on the buffers display for already opened markdown files.

@JohnDoe: See edit
